# How to change error message text in kartik fileinput

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I am using kartik yii2 widget fileinput. I set 'maxFileSize' to 1024. When uploaded file exceeds maximum allowed size, error message shows up, I want to change this error text and show it in Georgian language. How can I achieve this?
Here is my code:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'photo_name')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'options'=>[
                    'id'=>'upload-img',
                    'multiple'=>false,
                    'accept'=>'image/*',
                ],
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                    'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp'],
                    'browseLabel'=>'browse',
                    'captionLabel'=> '',
                    'removeLabel'=>'remove',
                    'browseClass' => 'btn btn-success',
                    'uploadClass' => 'btn btn-info',
                    'removeClass' => 'btn btn-danger',
                    'showPreview' => true,
                    'showCaption' => false,
                    'showRemove' => true,
                    'showUpload' => false,
                    'overwriteInitial'=>false,
                    'dropZoneEnabled'=>false,
                    'showClose' => false,
                    'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                    'maxFileSize'=>1024
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

I need to change this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need add this line into 'pluginOptions' and custom it:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'photo_name')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                'options'=>[
                    'id'=>'upload-img',
                    'multiple'=>false,
                    'accept'=>'image/*',
                ],
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    'msgSizeTooLarge' => 'File "{name}" (<b>{size} KB</b>) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of <b>{maxSize} KB</b>.',
                ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `tooBig` option inside the model validation rule where you specify the `maxSize` of the file your rule should look like below

```
[[ 'photo_name'] , 'file' , 'extensions' => 'pdf, jpg' , 'maxSize' => 1024000 , 'tooBig' => 'Limit is 1024KB' ] ,
```

For displaying it in `georgian` or any other than english you should look into the [**`Message Translation`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n#message-translation)